# "petition on X" in "Response to We The People Petition on the Protests in Hong Kong"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, headlinese

I am confused about [this headline](https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/response/response-we-people-petition-protests-hong-kong):

> Response to We the People Petition **on** the Protests in Hong Kong

It's the title of an official White House response to a [We The People petition](https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/) titled "Support Hong Kong Democracy and Prevent A Second Tiananmen Massacre in Hong Kong".

Is "*on*" a little weird?  So, it is a "*petition* ***on*** *something*", not a "*petition* ***about*** *something*". Does that mean I should write "*a request* ***on*** *something*", not "*a request* ***about*** *something*" too?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the grammar of *headlines* - an ill-defined concept which has little or nothing to do with standard English grammar.

Comment: I think it should remain open - it's non-standard, but news and press releases are important texts for non-native speakers to be able to understand and I think would be a common source of questions.

Comment: The simplifications common in title writing are not the topic of this question. If you wrote the title "properly", you might get "*Our* Response to *the* We the People Petition on the Protests in Hong Kong." but the question regarding "on" would still be valid.

Comment: meatie, I'll vote to reopen this question, but in the future please supply complete examples when you ask questions.  It can be difficult to understand partial examples.  Additional context is helpful, too, if you have any to provide.

Answer (score 2):

Using *on* is OK. It is like saying:

> Response to We the People Petition **regarding/concerning** the Protests in Hong Kong.

See the definition [on](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/on) sense 17.